# Using Two different tables for authentication in codeigniter and Ion Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

I am using Ion Auth for user authentication. The system i am trying to build needs two different users tables for client and admin. As in the application/config/ion_auth.php i can change only one table name, how i can make sure two controllers uses two different users table?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create groups instead? You can use the create_group method
then just check if the user belongs to that group.

Just create a Client group and an Admin group. You can also add more like Moderator group, etc.

This way is more convenient that having more than 1 users table

Answer (score 0):

Make new tables with needed fields and relate it to `group_id` in `users_groups`.

Answer (score 0):

Each table in a database should represent an entity. Since you need an entity User for authentication purposes you should have one table for all users. After that you can create tables for Admin and Client and create relationships between those and the Users table.